# Pressing the enter key to fire Onclick function, with multiple forms

Tags: jquery, onclick, enter

Idea: I'm trying to use the enter key to fire an onClick function from a submit input in #form1 without the enter key also firing off #form2 onclick function.

Issue: I got this code to work but the problem is my page has 2 forms and when I click enter from the 1st form's input field, it also fires the onClick for the 2nd form.

Question: Is there a way to hit enter from the 1st form's input field without firing off the 2nd form's onClick?

Notes: I've searched up and down in StackExchange and tried multiple answers but none seem to be working properly.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">

   <script>
    function post1() {
        alert("Hey");
    }

    function post2() {
        alert("Hey Again");
    }
    </script>


<form id="form1">
 <input type="text" id="city1" class="form-control" required>
  </div><br />
  <br />
<input type="button" onclick="post1();" value="Post Ad!" id="sub1" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
</form>

<form id="form2">
 <input type="text" id="city2" class="form-control" required>
  </div><br />
  <br />
<input type="button" onclick="post2();" value="Post Ad!" id="sub2" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
</form>

<script>
$(document).on('keyup keypress', 'form input[type="text"]', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sub1").click();    
        return false;
    }
});
$(document).on('keyup keypress', 'form input[type="text"]', function(e) {
      if(e.keyCode == 13) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $("#sub2").click();    
          return false;
      }
});
</script>
```

I'm sorry if I missed a post that gives this answer, if so please someone reference me to that location so that I may understand this issue better and move on. 
Thank you in advanced.

### *The Fix for those who have the same issue!*

Thanks to [Jazzepi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/310297/jazzepi) for the answer!

**Change** --> $(document).on('keyup keypress', **'form input[type="text"]'**, function(e) {...
**To** --> $(document).on('keyup keypress', **'form input[id="city1"]'**, function(e) {...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here in your code. You've attached an event delegate that responds to the same type of element. Because both listeners have `form input[type="text"]` each one will fire when you click on something that is a child of document, and matches that css selector. You need something that will discriminate between the two. Instead of what you have you could try `#city1` and `#city2` in the second argument to each of your on $.on calls.

```
$(document).on('keyup keypress', 'form input[type="text"]', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sub1").click();    
        return false;
    }
});

$(document).on('keyup keypress', 'form input[type="text"]', function(e) {
      if(e.keyCode == 13) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $("#sub2").click();    
          return false;
      }
});
```

Comment: You rock!! That fixed it!

Comment: @DustinLawrence Please accept the answer if it works for you :) And no problem. Easy to get hung up on small things.

Comment: One last question, is it possible to add multiple input #IDs into the 2nd argument in the $.on calls?

Comment: @DustinLawrence You need to look at the jquery api docs. If you look at on http://api.jquery.com/on/ you'll see that you pass it something called a "selector". You can see the selectors from a link on the left side of the page. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ and then you'll need to find one that can take multiple ids. Such a thing exists :) http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: No problem. Teach a man to fish, etc. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code, I noticed you have `else` clauses without prior `if` clauses in your function definitions. In addition, try to bind those handlers on the submit event and not the keypress or keyup event, because I think it would be impossible to prevent the default (prevent the form from submitting) if there is no submit button.

Comment: For better understanding I just removed the IF / Else statments. I'm more focused on the lower script.